# REST API auth error : WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, authentication, woocommerce-rest-api

Been trying to fetch products from WooCommerce REST API now forever and my brain is bleeding :'( I followed all instructions on [woocommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) and [github/woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-REST-API) and I can't for my life get anything in Postman with **Basic Auth**:

[image]

But when I select **Auth 1.0** - I get all products:

[image]

But then if I take the **Auth 1.0** generated URL and put it in my browser:

[image]

..Instructions under *Authentication over HTTP* ([here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http)) describes the parameters which are generated in URL automatically when i select **Auth 1.0** in Postman - but how am I gonna generate those in my React component?

```
const APP_URL = 'http://0.0.0.0:80'
const CONSUMER_KEY = 'ck_xxxx'
const CONSUMER_SECRET = 'cs_xxxx'
const PRODUCT_URL = `${APP_URL}/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=${CONSUMER_KEY}&consumer_secret=${CONSUMER_SECRET}`

fetch(PRODUCT_URL).then(res => {
    if(res.status === 200){
      return json
    } else {
      console.log("ERROR RESPONSE STATUS: " + status);
    }
  }).then( json => {
    console.log(json)
  })
})
```

So thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem may be solved by below code using "Interceptor" concept...

```
 import {
  Injectable,
  // Injector
 } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
// import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { config } from '../config/config';

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    // private injector: Injector,
    // private router: Router
  ) { }

  private includeWooAuth(url) {
    const wooAuth = `consumer_key=${config.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${config.secretKey}`;
    const hasQuery = url.includes('?');
    let return_url = '';
    if (hasQuery) {
      return_url =  wooAuth;
    } else {
      return_url = '?' + wooAuth;
    }
    return return_url;
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    const authRequest = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        // Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.getToken()}`
      },
      url: `${config.basePath}/${request.url}${this.includeWooAuth(request.url)}`
    });

    return next.handle(authRequest)
      .catch(err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 0) {
          console.log('Check Your Internet Connection And Try again Later');
        } else if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
          // auth.setToken(null);
          // this.router.navigate(['/', 'login']);
        }
        return Observable.throw(err);
      });
  }
}
```

This code will be kept into **http.interceptor.ts**. Obviously, you should initialize the consumer key and other details of woocommerce API into a constant variable. After that you create a **service** for show the list of the product like this:

```
retriveProducts(query: ProductQuery = {}): Observable<RetriveProductsResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`products`, {params: this.wooHelper.includeQuery(query), observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map(value => this.wooHelper.includeResponseHeader(value)),
        catchError(err => this.wooHelper.handleError(err)));
  }
```

And call this service to the **product.ts** file like this:

```
getProducts() {
    this.woocommerceProductsService.retriveProducts()
       .subscribe(productResponse => {
        this.products = productResponse.products;
       }, error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

I have used these above code into my project. I think it will help you.

Comment: How do I only set the my keys like 
`
intercept(req, next) {
    const authorizedRequest = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Username: 'ck_6a5ee3d6d0058cf34d3d3a8579ef30b0bdd5',
        Password: 'cs_96ea415d32d1f3160fc788654b40292fb03fc'

      }
    });
    return next.handle(authorizedRequest);
  }
`
Above method doesn't works for me